# Prove that if $f(1) = 0$, then $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x, y > 0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Suppose that $f$ is a function such that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for all
>    $x > 0$. Prove that if $f(1) = 0$, then $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all
>    $x, y > 0$

I've tried applying the Mean Value Theorem, such that $f'(x) = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} = \frac {1}{x}$, where $y = f(x)$ if *continuous* on $[a,b]$ and *differentiable* on $(a,b)$ such that there exists at least one point $c ∈ (a,b)$.

I'm probably wrong, but i don't know how do i really approach this question and what they are really asking for (e.g. $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function which is searched is the logarithm which is the inverse of the exponential function.

A special property of the exponential function is that it is a group homomorphism (or better say isomorphism) from the abelian group $\Bbb R$ with addition as group operation to the abelian group $\Bbb R^+$ with multiplication. So you have a map
$$ \exp \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^+ $$
with the property
$$ \exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y). $$

The equation 
$$ f(xy)= f(x)f(y) $$
is the corresponding equation the inverse of $\exp$. So that is what is behind this equation.

If you want to prove equality and derivates are involved it is always a good way to try to show that a the derivate vanishes and the equality holds at some point.

So here you can define the function

$$F(x) = f(xy) - f(x)-f(y), $$
 show that

$$ F'(x) =(f(xy) - f(x)-f(y))' = f'(xy)y - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{y}{xy}- \frac{1}{x} =0 $$

and you know that

$$ F(1) = f(y) -f(1)- f(y) = 0.  $$